# Merging dataframes in R - resulting dataframe is too large

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, inner-join

I am trying to merge two dataframes in R, joining them by the one column that they share.
Here are screenshots of the two dataframes, and I am merging on the column "INC_KEY".

[image]

[image]

This is the code I have written to merge the two dataframes:
dp <- inner_join(d,p,by="INC_KEY")

d has 177156 observations, and p has 1641137 observations, but the final merged dataframe has 8416113 observations, which does not make sense to me. I have also tried changing the inner_join function above to the merge function, but I still get the same result. I am wondering how to fix this code so that the merged dataframe has a realistic number of observations - thanks so much for any help!

Comment: You should provide a small but reproducible example for us to copy and verify our answers. Don’t add data/code as images. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have duplicates in either `d` or `p` or both of them. Try keeping only one row for each unique `INC_KEY` value before joining.

```
library(dplyr)

dp <- inner_join(d %>% distinct(INC_KEY, .keep_all = TRUE),
                 p %>% distinct(INC_KEY, .keep_all = TRUE),by="INC_KEY")
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your `INC_KEY` is not a unique identifier. Here is a simplified example:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(key = c("A", "B", "C", "A"),
                  val1 = 1:4)
df2 <- data.frame(key = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "B"),
                  val2 = 1:5)

inner_join(df1, df2, by = "key")

Joining, by = "key"
  key val1 val2
1   A    1    1
2   B    2    2
3   B    2    5
4   C    3    3
5   C    3    4
6   A    4    1
```

Because there are two values of "A" in the `key` column in `df1`, both rows match the one row of `df2` with "A". The one row in df1 with a `key` of "C" matches both rows with the `key` of "C" in `df2`. This is the expected behavior of an inner join with duplicated key values. The join returns all rows in the second data.frame that match each row in the first data.frame. If there are multiple matches, they are all returned.

If you want one row per `INC_KEY`, then you need to do something to your original data before the join, especially the rows are not complete duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The key column `INC_KEY` has duplicates in at least one of your tables. `inner_join` will then output a table with additional rows depending on the number of found duplicates minus the rows with `INC_KEY` missing in either `d`or `p`.

If you expect your new table to have the same number of rows as table `d`, then you need to aggregate the information in table `p` first; grouped by `INC_KEY`. Then you can perform `inner_join`.